# Errors mei_me 0000:00:03.0: timer: connect/disconnect timeout. after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, ubuntu-14.04

I upgraded from ubuntu 12.10 to 14.04 and now I get

> dmesg|grep mei

```
[   19.246502] mei_me 0000:00:03.0: irq 48 for MSI/MSI-X
[   24.280045] mei_me 0000:00:03.0: timer: connect/disconnect timeout.
[   24.280050] mei_me 0000:00:03.0: unexpected reset: dev_state = ENABLED
[   30.292023] mei_me 0000:00:03.0: timer: connect/disconnect timeout.
[   30.292030] mei_me 0000:00:03.0: unexpected reset: dev_state = ENABLED
[...]
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the discussion: [**Console gets message about mei_me timeout every 5 seconds**](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=168403)

You can either disable the `imei-me` module or turn off the management engine from your BIOS, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> during reboot.